# How can I alter humans to allow them the ability to choose the sex of their child in the ancient world?

Tags: biology, science-fiction, reproduction, ancient-history

Research shows that some creatures in the animal kingdom manipulate the sex of their child in order to maximize the number of grandchildren. Parents in good condition, based on health, size, dominance or other traits, would invest more in producing sons, whose inherited strength and bulk could help them better compete in the mating market and give them greater opportunities to produce more offspring. Conversely, mothers in poor condition would likely play it safe, producing more daughters, whose productivity is physiologically limited.

This setting takes place in the ancient world, before advances in medicine and technology. I want to biologically alter humans in a way that allows individuals to manipulate the sex of their children. How could this work? Would it make sense to put this ability in males or females?

Comment: My eyebrow has just risen to the sky... It takes time for a mother to give birth to a child. During this time the mother cannot make other children, while the father still can. If you wish to maximize the number of grandchildren you want a very skewed gender representation, with very few males and a lot of females. Productivity is no issue, as very (very very) few animals that we know of reached a natural resource bottleneck.

Comment: The way you word you question makes it sound like you may want to biologically alter humans in your world to allow for sex selection, rather than asking how historical humans would have done it (infanticide, as the top answer points out.) Is this the case? If so, you should probably clarify the question.

Comment: It makes no sense to "invest more" in sons if the primary goal is lots of grandchildren.   Men can produce a thousand children in a year (okay, a couple hundred is more realistic, if the culture allows) and women only 1-3, and they need breaks.  So you want more women than men or the men run out of non-pregnant partners.  Nor does the mothers "playing it safe" make any sense at all.  I recommend a pretty heavy rewrite. Your questions are usually a lot more thought-out.

Comment: @NofP According to [Fisher's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_principle) simply producing more females is not an optimal strategy. If there are more females than males then males will on average have greater reproductive success.

Comment: @Cyn I don't think you understand the question. Think about the question not as a species working together to grow as large as possible, but from the true evolutionary perspective of individuals in a species competing against each other to produce the most offspring. In a species where males compete for reproductive success producing weak males that can't compete is suboptimal. You'd be better off having a female whose fitness is less dependent on their strength. On the other hand, producing strong males that will outcompete their peers will have greater expected fitness than having a female.

Comment: @MikeNichols this is the ancient world, with societies and not a "Grok best hunter and therefore mate" world.  Nor would skewing the balance between males and females make the males less likely to be "strong" however you define it.  if parents raise sons in a resource-heavy way, fewer sons and more daughters is an advantage there because a higher percentage of sons will be "strong."  Also, if you expect a woman to produce children almost nonstop, she will have to be very physically strong (and even then, it's not easy). More daughters lessens that burden.

Comment: @Cyn I think answering this question might help: If having more females than males would result in more offspring why don't we already have many more females than males? The answer is Fisher’s principle. Reproductive competition between individuals in a species will always favor a 50:50 ratio. Being able to choose the sex of offspring will give a competitive advantage especially if there is male competition which the question assumes. Have a male if you know the child will grow up strong and have a female if you know the child will grow up weak.

Comment: @MikeNichols I still don't buy it but you should write it up as an answer (with some genetic alternation or whatever is needed). While it's true that an individual couple might have more grandchildren if they have more boys than girls, it only works for a population if there are enough girls. Otherwise, it's a pyramid scheme.  This is not something that would evolve (your link shows that) & genetically engineering it wouldn't do much after a couple generations.

Comment: @Cyn You miss my intent entirely. I'm not answering the question. I'm defending it. You said having more women than men would always be better and so the question didn't make any sense at all. I'm trying to help you see why the question makes sense. This phenomenon of parents choosing offspring's sex is theorized to exist and evolved to serve exactly the purpose the question is asking about: [Winning the Genetic Lottery: Biasing Birth Sex Ratio Results in More Grandchildren](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3707872/)

Comment: @MikeNichols Ehm, if I read the article correctly, you still want more females than males, and you want to be the male lineage to spread your genes across the largest number of females.  By the way, FYI, this problem is an extension of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm  to maximize the productivity with the smallest number of workers when tasks require pairing and the team mates have different efficiency.

Comment: @NofP For the irrelevant goal of maximizing the number of offspring of the population a female dominant strategy would be favored. Unfortunately, that isn't how biology (or human societies) function. Individuals act to maximize their own fitness. Not the fitness of their population. Spreading your genes is the ultimate evolutionary goal and that goal is not achieved by altering sex ratios in favor of female offspring. It can be achieved, however, by a situational sex-selection strategy as described in the original question.

Comment: @MikeNichols  You seem very passionate about spreading genes. Back to the question: thinking for one self is not how you ensure a high chance of your gene spreading. This is a cooperative game played over million of years, we should have learned it by now, don't you think? --- haha I know your answer "Need to spread geeeenes!" XD XD XD

Comment: @MikeNichols what would need to happen for this race to be more practical and think in terms of population growth rather than maximize their own fitness?

Answer (score 12):

It's very simple, **infanticide**. Death is a natural process and infanticide has been practised and probably still is in some societies. I shall try to avoid getting entangled in the abortion controversy. The ancient infanticide solution comes **after** birth of the child when the gender is visible.

> Infanticide, the killing of unwanted babies, was common throughout the
>   Roman Empire and other parts of the ancient world, according to a new
>   study.
>   http://www.nbcnews.com/id/42919668/ns/technology_and_science-science/t/archaeologists-document-ancient-baby-killing/#.XD8uUFz7Tb0

---

**China**

> Marco Polo wrote about seeing many babies exposed in Mani [11]. Sex
>   selective infanticide was common in China . Han Fei Tzu, a Chinese
>   philosopher in the 3rd century BC wrote that “As to children, a father
>   and mother when they produce a boy congratulate one another, but when
>   they produce a girl they put it to death”[12] .  Many Chinese tribes
>   practiced infanticide by putting the baby into a bucked of cold water,
>   called “baby water” [13] .  **The 2006 edition of a book** by two
>   prominent historians stated that **even by now, in China, infanticide
>   seemed more likely for a girl** than a boy.
>
> https://www.wikigender.org/wiki/history-of-infanticide/

Comment: This is the correct answer, the only answer available to the human species in "the ancient world"

Comment: There is an even easier form that may actually happen spontaneous abortion, it requires a lot less energy than carrying a child to full term then killing it. There is some evidence human may already change gender ratios this way naturally.

Comment: @John - That sounds interesting. Do you have any links to this evidence?

Comment: two different proposed mechanisms https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2199736 and https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24886317 The latter is more well studied in animals

Comment: @John : but before the late 20th century there wasn't any sure way to determine whether it will be a boy or girl, before the birth.

Answer (score 3):

In the animal kingdom, some species of reptiles, amphibians, and I think fish can do this by influencing the temperature of the environment in which their eggs develop.

Another possibility might be specific chemical factors in the food triggering the creation of mostly male or mostly female sperm cells.

Neither of which of course works with actual human beings, but for your fantasy creatures either or both might be a factor.

Answer (score 2):

It's kinda possible.
 The deciding factor for the sex of the baby will be the chromossome in the male spermatoziod, each espermatozoid have only one sexual chromosome.
 Some studies points that the spermatozoid with the 'x' chromossome are slower but more resistent than the 'y' spermatozoid which is faster but less resistent, that means if a couple has sex 5 or 4 days before the ovulation the 'x' ones will have more chance of fecuding, if they have sex in the ovulation period, the 'y' one have more chances being faster, the acid of the vagine can also play part on this, a more acid vagina can led to the death of the y spermatozoid, choosing some types of food can change the PH of the vagina helping this process.

In summary, if you want a boy, have sex on ovulation day and eat fruits an vegetables and less meat.
If you want a girl, have sex before the ovulation and eat a lot of red meat.

Answer (score 0):

**Unnecessary**

In ancient times (12000 years? 2000 years? 200 years? Nevermind, changes start to happen only in the Industrial Revolution) human culture had gender roles that demanded a reasonable balance between them for the society to remain stable. A society with few men in relation to the total number of women or vice versa was fatally weak and vulnerable against others.

Also consider the basics of demography for almost the entire human existence:

1. 25% ~ 40% of children [died before their 5th birthday](https://ourworldindata.org/child-mortality-in-the-past), 35% ~ 60% before their 15th birthday.
2. women (girls!) married at 11, got pregnant the first time at 12, then had seven to fifteen children, if they were lucky not to die as a result of pregnancy problems.
3. children who reached adulthood managed to live to be about forty, luckily they lived to be sixty.

In these conditions (which still exist in some places in [Sub-Saharan Africa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMo3nZHVrZ4)) it makes little sense to choose the child's gender. Some cultures even refrain from [naming babies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_ancient_Rome#Naming) before they are certain that the effort will be worth it and that the newborn may or may not live.

In the conditions that we find in the countries that have completed the [demographic transition](https://populationeducation.org/what-demographic-transition-model/) (infant mortality is low, the population is urban, adolescents most of the time do not become pregnant, women have [1 or 2 children](https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/children-per-woman-un?tab=chart&time=1981..2015&country=Eastern%20Asia+Europe+Northern%20America+Oceania+South%20America+South-Eastern%20Asia) and you can expect to live around or more than [seventy or eighty years](https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/life-expectancy?time=1970..2019&country=Europe+Americas+CHN+Oceania+ISR+IRN+JPN+KOR)) choosing the genre even makes some sense. A great example of this is China now, after the end of the one-child policy: as culturally having a male child has always been valued there have been many abortions of girls and today the country has a [huge gender gap](https://www.populationpyramid.net/china/2019/) that has made any [woman willing to marry rare and disputed](https://www.bbc.com/worklife/article/20170213-why-millions-of-chinese-men-are-staying-single).